# jquery accordion menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div specified as an accordion that I "activate" with the js .accordion

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion();
```

however I'm only getting plain text. I thought the end result would be all the  tags turned into accordion headers. 
i have it here in the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/toocool/Z2C9j/

Comment: Works fine as long as you include jQuery and jQuery UI: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Z2C9j/2/

Comment: Magic never happens. If you don't add the required libraries (here jQuery and jQuery UI), nothing will get changed.

Comment: I could be mistaken but accordion is a part of Jquery UI...the fiddle you provided has neither jquery nor jquery ui.

Comment: hm. thanks. i would've voted for your answer if you posted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey you need the Jquery and Jquery UI plugin which wasn't in your fiddle other than that it was fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2C9j/3/

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: points for including the script. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I could be mistaken but accordion is a part of Jquery UI...the fiddle you provided has neither jquery nor jquery ui.  You have to include the jquery and jquery ui libraries.